# Prevent User from spamming Esc to close form while its loading?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a main form that a user opens. It usually takes a few seconds and thus I set Application.Echo False to prevent screen updating.

However, if the user gets frustrated for some reason and spams Esc, this will end the code and usually produce an error.

How can I prevent them from pressing Esc til the form is loaded and open?

Comment: Even if you "fix" this, there are plenty of others ways that users can mess with stuff if they so choose... the only real solution is training for the users (including followup). (See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378))

Comment: @ashleedawg is there anyway to ensure that the Form_Load event runs uninterrupted?

Comment: See this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/826765/how-to-enforce-or-disable-the-startup-options-in-an-access-database-pr

Comment: What in the world is "spamming Esc"?  A web search only brought up a few gaming website references.  Does this really have a mainstream meaning?